# Является ли предложение сложным?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение

Стоит ли ставить запятую?

*Сейчас мне важно(,) чем я буду сегодня заниматься.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Сейчас мне важно, чем я буду сегодня заниматься.***

Да, это сложное (сложноподчиненное) предложение. Запятая ставится после первого простого безличного предложения (оно же главное), в котором сказуемое выражено категорией состояния – ***важно***.

**Дополнительная информация**

> [**Безличное предложение**](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/primeryi-bezlichnyih-predlozheniy.html) — это простое односоставное предложение, в котором главный член обозначает действие или состояние, совершающееся без действующего лица.
>
> В безличных предложениях сказуемое выражается словами различных частей речи и их сочетаниями.

В таких предложениях нет подлежащего. Например:
*Вечереет; Пахнет сеном; В комнате накурено.*
Субъект может быть обозначен, но он не в именительном падеже:
***Мне** грустно; **Мне** нужно действовать; Кажется, **ему** здесь тоскливо одному; **Нам** не видать таких сражений!* (М. Лермонтов).

*Сейчас мне важно **(что?),** чем я буду сегодня заниматься.*

Здесь второе предложение (***я буду заниматься***) зависит от первого и относится к [**изъяснительным придаточным**](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/primeryi-slozhnopodchinennyih-predlozheniy-pridatochnyim-izyasnitelnyim.html), которые отвечают на вопросы косвенных падежей.

> В сложноподчиненных предложениях с придаточным изъяснительным слова, к которым оно присоединяется, имеют значение речи, мысли, восприятия, чувства, состояния:
> <...>
> **•** *надо, видно, жаль, странно, удивительно, совестно, известно, понятно, **важно**, хорошо.*

**Примеры** из Нацкорпуса русского языка:

*А мне уже плевать, что государство не выигрывает, **мне важно, что** я проигрываю.* [Михаил Жванецкий. Осторожно, люди! // «Огонек». № 14, 1991]

*Мне ведь ваше мнение неинтересно, **мне важно, что** я сама слышу.* [Булат Окуджава. Путешествие дилетантов (Из записок отставного поручика Амирана Амилахвари) (1971-1977)]

― ***Мне неважно, куда** выходить отсюда, лишь бы вон…* [Дмитрий Быков. Орфография (2002)]