# Обособление слова "интересно" в утвердительном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение

Ставится ли запятая после слова "интересно", когда предложение не вопросительное, а утвердительное? Например:

– Почему ты спрашиваешь?
– [Потому, что мне] **Интересно** в каком году это случилось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Интересно,** в каком году это случилось.*

Вопросительное или утвердительное предложение – в данном случае совершенно неважно.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение. Запятая ставится после первого простого [безличного предложения](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/primeryi-bezlichnyih-predlozheniy.html) (оно же главное), состоящего из одного слова – сказуемого категории состояния. От него можно задать вопрос: *Интересно что?* И далее идёт [изъяснительное придаточное предложение](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/primeryi-slozhnopodchinennyih-predlozheniy-pridatochnyim-izyasnitelnyim.html).

Можете посмотреть более подробный ответ на [похожий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467494/%D0%AF%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC).